# What causes reachability check failure on EC2 instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2

I have an EC2 instance which is stopped at the end of each working day, and then started again the following morning via a Control-M job. Most instances start with no problems, however occasionally we are seeing an error as the instance reachability check fails upon startup.

The following is taken from the system log:

```
[    8.688983] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    8.693873] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    8.697700] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    8.702012] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[   11.203839] ixgbevf: Unable to start - perhaps the PF Driver isn't up yet
[   11.575869] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   12.594246] ixgbevf: Unable to start - perhaps the PF Driver isn't up yet
[   19.465602] Adding Red Hat flag eBPF/event.
```

I'm not very experienced with this kind of troubleshooting, has anyone seen this problem themselves, or able to provide information as to why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question can better be answered by AWS Support.

Answer (score 0):

The instance status check failure indicates an issue with the reachability of the instance. This issue occurs due to operating system-level errors such as the following: Failure to boot the operating system. Failure to mount the volumes correctly.